# Processing Multipart/mixed on Twisted

Tags: python, json, rest, twisted, multipart

After having a Twisted Rest interface where JSON requests are processed, now I face the need of processing multipart/mixed requests where a JSON and a binary file will come together.

After a bit testing with curl, I've realized that request variable will be filled with a '*file*' type and I'd like to know if there's any method in Twisted to handle this kind of requests properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old post, I remember solving this with [email module](http://docs.python.org/library/email), it anyone is interested...

Comment: could you be a little bit more detailed?

Comment: More or less what I did is to get the response as a mail instance, where I can easily get multipart contents.